# Counting the number of swaps in `base::sort` in R

Tags: r, sorting, swap

The `base::sort` function return the ascending (descending) order of an unordered vector.

```R
X <- c(3,4,2,5,1)
sort(X)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there any way to count the number of swaps performed by the function to obtain the ordered vector?

Comment: What is the expected number of swaps in the given example?

Comment: @tmfmnk : it is 4: `(3,4,2,5,1)` - `(1,4,2,5,3)` - `(1,2,4,5,3)` - `(1,2,3,5,4)` - `(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: isnt that depending on the sort algorithm. Also 2 could be a valid number, couldn't it?
`(3,4,2,5,1)` - `(2,3,4,5,1)` - `(1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: I think `base::sort` has a variety of sorting algorithms implemented. Are you interested in `base::sort` in general, or the number of swaps of a particular method?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I'm interested in the minimum number of swaps required to obtain the ordered vector. base::sort use the auto/radix method for small vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stringdist` package can do this kind of calculation on strings.  So if you have a small enough number of symbols, you could use that.  For example:

```r
X <- c(3,4,2,5,1)
Y <- sort(X)

# Convert to strings
tostring <- function(x, symbols = sort(unique(x))) {
  alphabet <- c(letters, LETTERS)
  if (length(symbols) > length(alphabet))
    stop("You need a bigger alphabet!")
  if (any(! x %in% symbols))
    stop("x has unknown symbols!")
  paste(alphabet[match(x, symbols)], collapse="")
}

symboldist <- function(x, y, method = "osa") {
  symbols <- unique(c(x, y))
  stringdist::stringdist(tostring(x, symbols), tostring(y, symbols), 
                         method = method)
}

symboldist(X, Y)
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Edited to add:  It looks as though the "transposition distance" is what you want.  Here's an implementation based on a Javascript one found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-transpositions-in-a-permutation/:

```r
# Translation of Javascript transposition distance calculation
# from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-transpositions-in-a-permutation/

transpositionDistance <- function(P) {
  dfs <- function(i) {
    result <- 0
    while (!visited[i]) {
      visited[i] <<- TRUE
      i <- goesTo[i]
      result <- result + 1
    }
    result
  }
  
  # Convert P into a permutation of 1:n
  P <- match(P, sort(P))
  
  n <- length(P)
  if (!all(seq_len(n) %in% P))
    stop("this only works on permutations of unique elements")
  visited <- logical(n)
  goesTo <- integer(n)
  
  goesTo[P] <- seq_along(P)
  transpositions <- 0
  for (i in seq_len(n))
    if (!visited[i])
      transpositions <- transpositions + dfs(i) - 1
  transpositions
}

transpositionDistance(c(3,4,2,5,1))
#> [1] 4
transpositionDistance(c(1,3,5,2,4))
#> [1] 3
transpositionDistance(c(1,4,3,2,5))
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, trying a different vector, for example, `X <- c(1,3,5,2,4)`, the function `symboldist(X, Y)` return 4, instead of 3 (the minimum number of swaps required).

Comment: Using `method = "dl"` gives 3 on that pair.  You'll need to read the help on `stringdist()` to figure out which distance metric most closely matches your expectations.

Comment: in both cases (and trying the other methods), the string `X <- c(1,4,3,2,5)` does not return `1`, as expected.

Comment: That works perfectly, also to larger vector. It is now easy to compute the parity of transpositions of a given unordered vector.